# Keeping track of Gas costs

Tags: gas

I have a smart contract that allows for several different user to batch tx's for their ERC20 Token distribution.
In this SC the user send some ether to the smart contract, and some tokens.

I want the user to be able to withdrwaw the tokens it doesnt use for which im using:

```
///@notice  Distributes a constant quantity of tokens to all the specified addresses.
///@dev Distribution will only occur when a distribute function is called, and passed the correct parameters, it is not the smart contracts job to produce the addresses or determine the ammount
///@param index The airdrop token to withdraw based in the the array in which is saved
///@param _amount  The amount to be withdrawn from the smart contract
function withdrawTokens(
    uint index,
    uint _amount
)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
  Airdrop memory airdrop = airdrops[index];
  airdrop.tokenSC.transfer(owner,_amount);
}
```

To withdraw the tokens, which works like a charm.

When withdrawing ether though. I need to be able to keep track how much ether they have spent so far.

Any idea how to go on about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapping and the fallback function

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

function () public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

When they use some of their deposits you decrement their balance

```
function useDeposit(uint256 amount) internal {
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
}
```